# How I can watching to change input value for validation form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can watching to change input value for validation form?

I have validation script for my form.

This function work normal, but it start always only after click.
How I can watching when change `input.val()`

```
form# send - form
input(type = "text"
 data - validate = "name")
button(class = "form_btn")


function validator(el, validName) {
 var mask_name = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,20}$/;
 var el = el;

 if (validName == "name") {
  var el_val = $(el).val();
  if (mask_name.test(el_val)) {
   $(el).removeClass('error');
  } else {
   $(el).addClass('error');
  }
 }
});

function mainValidation() {

 if ($('#send-form')) {
  $('input').each(function() {
   var this_el = $(this);
   var validName = $(this).data("validate");

   validator(this_el, validName);
  });
 }
};

$('.form_btn').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 mainValidation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set up an event handler for the `input` event of the input field in question.

```
 // You need to provide a selector that references the input field properly
 $('inputSelectorHere').on('input', mainValidation);
```

You could also wait until the user leaves the input field to do the validation by using the `blur` event:

```
 // You need to provide a selector that references the input field properly
 $('inputSelectorHere').on('blur', mainValidation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the input change event:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    var this_el = $(this);
    var validName =  $(this).data( "validate" );

    validator( this_el, validName );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
('input').on('change', function() {
    mainValidation();
});
```

Now you are listening the changes on all the input fields. When a field change, it will call your function mainValidation().

Let me know.
Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer may be correct, but it is helpful if you can explain why this will work, as it becomes a permanent record which other people may read at some later date. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more details

Comment: Hi, thank you for your tip :)